# How to compress PDF at client side using npm?

Tags: pdf, npm

I need to compress a PDF at client side browser application and then get it uploaded to the server.

I successfully tried this approach for images using below npm module,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/compressorjs

But so far did not find a library which could compress pdf's.

Just FYI, I have tried ghostscript but that is after the file is uploaded to the server. But in this case I need to compress the file at client side.

Comment: For lossless compression, try https://www.npmjs.com/package/coherentpdf in particular the squeeze function. Of course, on well-made PDFs, the improvements will be minimal. If you want to, for example, downsample images in the PDF, I don't know of a client side solution for that.

Comment: I tried it but it is not supporting latest npm version.